# Does a compact Lie group action on a family of compact manifolds have diffeomorphic fixed point submanifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions, fibre-bundles

Let $\pi: M\to B$ be a fiber bundle of smooth manifolds with $B$ connected and each fiber of $\pi$ is a compact manifold. Let $G$ be a compact Lie group acting smoothly on $M$ such that
$\pi(g\cdot m)=\pi(m)$. It is clear that $G$ acts smoothly on each fiber $M_b$ for $b\in B$.

Noe fix a $g\in G$. For each $b\in B$ we consider the fixed point submanifold $M_b^g\subset M_b$.

My question is: when $b$ varies, does the diffeomorphic type of $M_b^g$ unchanged?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is yes.

Since $G$ is compact, there is a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric on $M$ (by averaging any metric). The orthogonal distribution to the fiber for this metric is a $G$-invariant Ehresmann connection, and the parallel transport for this connection thus commutes with the $G$-action.

This shows that the action of $G$ on any two fibers are conjugate. In particular, the fixed loci are diffeomorphic.

Comment: More generally, two nearby smooth actions of a compact Lie group on a closed manifold are equivariantly diffeomorphic. This is proved in [Palais, Equivalence of nearby differentiable actions of a compact group. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 67 (1961), 362–364], https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society/volume-67/issue-4/Equivalence-of-nearby-differentiable-actions-of-a-compact-group/bams/1183524251.full.